# how do i get non-repeated character and its count in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here is my code. What should I modify of this code to get the output as
"T-1 
 r-1
 a-1
 e-1 "

(other characters are repeating. So no need to print the others)

```
function different() {

    var retureArr = [];
    var count = 0;
    var complete_name = "Trammell";
    var stringLength = complete_name.length;

    for (var t = 0; t < stringLength; t++) {
        for (var s = 0; s < stringLength; s++) {
            var com1 = complete_name.charAt(t);
            var com2 = complete_name.charAt(s);

            if (com1 != com2) {
                retureArr[count] = com1;
                count++;
            }
        }

        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please state what is your requirement. Not what the desired output is. Also, note that your function does not return nor print a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You need to count the number of occurrences of each character in a dictionary. Then you can print them based on the count being equal to 1.

```
var retureArr = [];
var complete_name = "Trammell";

for (var i = 0; i < complete_name.length; i++)
{
    var key = complete_name[i];
    if (!(key in retureArr))
    {
        retureArr[key] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        retureArr[key] = retureArr[key] + 1;
    }
}

var output = "";
for (var key in retureArr)
{
    if (retureArr[key] == 1)
    {
        output += key + "-" + retureArr[key] + " ";
    }
}

alert(output);
```

This alerts the following string:

```
T-1 r-1 a-1 e-1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Millie Smith. It's working well. If i want to print other repeating characters also what modification should i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "other repeating characters"? You could remove the last `if` statement that checks if the `count` is 1.

Comment: It means actually repeating characters. Here your code prints non-repeating characters only.

Comment: Ok Millie Smith I modified it as i want. Thank you sir!!

Comment: What attribute can i keep as a unique id or something else in html elements. It shouldn't be able to modify by the browser.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. Why not ask another question to the SO community?

Answer (score 0):

This works. but perhaps isn't the most efficient!

```
var string = "input string";
var stringList = [];
var outputString = "";

for (var i=0; i < string.length; i++){
    var charObject = {"Char": string.charAt(i), "Passed": false};   
    stringList.push(charObject);
}


for (var i=0; i < stringList.length; i++){
    if(!stringList[i].Passed && stringList[i].Char != " "){
        var currentCount = countOccurrences(string, stringList[i].Char);
        if(currentCount == 1){
            outputString += stringList[i].Char+"-"+currentCount + " ";
        }
        stringList[i].Passed = true;
    }
}

console.log(outputString);

function countOccurrences(string, char){
    var count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < string.length; i++){
        if(string.charAt(i) == char){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```